# Swift only print first character of my sql server query result

Tags: sql-server, swift, xcode

I'm new in Swift and Xcode. I'm trying to get data from SQL Server in Swift. Connection is successful.
Today I realised that, when I run a query in xcode, xcode getting only first character of integer column value.
For Example; my query string is like that:

```
var ozetquery:String = "SELECT PRO_NAME AS NAME, Sum(PRO_COUNT) AS COUNTER FROM PRO_LIST GROUP BY PRO_NAME"
```

PRO_NAME is nvarchar(100) an PRO_COUNT is int in SQL-SERVER

my Swift code of getting data is like that:

```
client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
    client.delegate = self
    client.connect(strIP,username: strUName,password: strPass,database: strDBName){ success in
        if success {
            self.client.execute(self.ozetquery) {
                results in
                for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                    for row in table {
                        for (columnName, value) in row {
                            print("\(columnName) = \(value)")
                            }}}
                self.client.disconnect()
            }}
        else{}
    }
```

Normally, my query result is like that:

```
ProA
15
ProB
35
ProC
42
ProD
29
```

But, in xcode, it prints like that:

```
ProA
1
ProB
3
ProC
4
ProD
2
```

How can I fix this result in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found th solution by changing SQL query statement like that:

```
var ozetquery:String = "SELECT PRO_NAME AS NAME, CAST(Sum(PRO_COUNT) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS COUNTER FROM PRO_LIST GROUP BY PRO_NAME"
```